# Parse multiple fields from a text & reformat into desired output form

Tags: bash, shell

here some /paths/files :

```
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/a/*.trc
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/b/*.trc
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/c/*.trc
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/x/*.trc
```

in the files, sometime i got somes text like that

```
20/12/2019,20:00:04.631 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1> "
```

(here's an example :)

```
grep -Rn "(ERR) tentativ" /mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/ *

/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/a/2019_12_20/CF0030/CF0030_00.trc:11:20/12/2019,00:00:01.517 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/b/2019_12_20/CF0031/CF0031_00.trc:13:20/12/2019,00:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/c/2019_12_20/CF0044/CF0044_04.trc:11:20/12/2019,04:00:01.516 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/d/2019_12_20/CF0017/CF0017_04.trc:13:20/12/2019,04:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
```

i would like to have an output like this :

```
cat ./extract.txt

CF0030;Line 11: 20/12/2019,00:00:01.517 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
CF0031;Line 13: 20/12/2019,00:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
CF0044;Line 44: 20/12/2019,04:00:01.516 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
```

where :

```
CF0030;                                                 = name of the parent DIRECTORY of the file
Line 11:                                                = number of the line where the error is    (grep -n)
21/11/2019,22:34:55.520 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>   = the last field of the "grep -Rn"
```

All have to be in a file named : "extract.txt"

Can someone help pls?

Comment: I think there is an expectation that you should have attempted this yourself first before asking for help and that you post what you tried in the question

Answer (score 1):

! Assuming no file/folder contains `:` in their name.

Assuming this is `grep`'s output:

```
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/a/2019_12_20/CF0030/CF0030_00.trc:11:20/12/2019,00:00:01.517 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/b/2019_12_20/CF0031/CF0031_00.trc:13:20/12/2019,00:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/c/2019_12_20/CF0044/CF0044_04.trc:11:20/12/2019,04:00:01.516 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
/mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/d/2019_12_20/CF0017/CF0017_04.trc:13:20/12/2019,04:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
```

Assuming this is the expected output:

```
CF0030;Line 11:20/12/2019,00:00:01.517 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
CF0031;Line 13:20/12/2019,00:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
CF0044;Line 11:20/12/2019,04:00:01.516 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
CF0017;Line 13:20/12/2019,04:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
```

====

- Snippet 1, using `sed`:

```
grep -Rn "(ERR) tentative" /mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/* |
  sed -nE 's_^[^:]*/([^:/]*)/[^:/]*:_\1;Line _p'
```

- Snippet 2, using `awk` (with a printing loop):

```
grep -Rn "(ERR) tentative" /mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/* |
  awk -F: 'NF > 2 { n=split($1,path,"/"); printf "%s;Line %s", path[n-1], $2;
           for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf ":%s",$(i); print ""; }'
```

```
CF0030;Line 11:20/12/2019,00:00:01.517 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
CF0031;Line 13:20/12/2019,00:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
CF0044;Line 11:20/12/2019,04:00:01.516 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<1>
CF0017;Line 13:20/12/2019,04:00:02.527 : (ERR) tentativeDialogue=<2>
```

- Snippet 3, using `awk` (without printing loop):

```
grep -Rn "(ERR) tentative" /mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/* |
  awk -F: -vOFS=: 'NF > 2 { n=split($1, path, "/"); $1=path[n-1]; $2="Line "$2;
                   sub(FS, ";", $0); print; }'
```

- Snippet 4, using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -Rn "(ERR) tentative" /mnt/export/TRACES_EXPLOITATION_CCT/* |
  while IFS=: read -ra line; do
    [[ $line ]] || continue
    tmp=${line[0]} tmp=${tmp%/*} l1=${tmp##*/} l2="Line ${line[1]}"
    printf %s "$l1;$l2"
    printf :%s "${line[@]:2}"
    echo
  done
```

Comment: Note that usually, something that's more "write my program for me" than "how do I solve problem-X I encountered while writing program-Y myself?" would be closed, not answered; especially when we have existing Q&A entries elsewhere in the knowledgebase already showing the same techniques.

Comment: You are right. I wouldn't know how to find a suitable knowledge base example for this though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok great that's work perfectly.

for answer to a question i seen, i wrote this code by myself :

```
#grep -Rn "(ERR) tentativ" $dir * | cut -d '/' -f 7- | sed 's/\/.*trc/;/' | sed 's/.:/;Line\ /'> $dir/file.txt
```

this works but it's optimizable.

And tyhe answer u tell to me is OK !

thanks you all!